# rsyslog.conf file is not present under /etc/ in Fedora 25

Tags: fedora, configuration

I am running Fedora 25. I am unable to locate the file `rsyslog.conf` under `/etc/`

The output of the command

```
ls /etc/*.conf
```

is

```
asound.conf                 kdump.conf       radvd.conf
brltty.conf                 krb5.conf        request-key.conf
chrony.conf                 ld.so.conf       resolv.conf
dleyna-server-service.conf  libaudit.conf    rygel.conf
dnsmasq.conf                libuser.conf     sestatus.conf
dracut.conf                 locale.conf      sos.conf
e2fsck.conf                 logrotate.conf   sysctl.conf
extlinux.conf               man_db.conf      tcsd.conf
fprintd.conf                memtest86+.conf  Trolltech.conf
fuse.conf                   mke2fs.conf      updatedb.conf
fwupd.conf                  mtools.conf      usb_modeswitch.conf
hba.conf                    nfs.conf         vconsole.conf
host.conf                   nfsmount.conf    wvdial.conf
idmapd.conf                 nsswitch.conf    xattr.conf
jwhois.conf                 passwdqc.conf
```

The output of the command

```
find / -name rsyslog.conf
```

gives the output

```
/usr/lib/dracut/modules.d/98syslog/rsyslog.conf
```

Why is it like that?

Comment: Does `rpm -q -l rsyslog` show that file in its list?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is showing `package rsyslog not installed`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rsyslog is not installed by default on Fedora Workstation (although it is in some other flavors of Fedora). Many use cases can be served by querying the systemd journal directly with `journalctl` or other tools. Or, you can install and configure rsyslog — `sudo dnf install rsyslog`, and then find the config file you were expecting.

Comment: Which one is better and why? `dnf install` & `yum install`

Comment: Long story. :) DNF is a newer replacement for Yum. On current Fedora, `yum` actually just calls `dnf`. Originally DNF had a lot of syntax changes, but there is work on fixing that so they become literally interchange and we retain better compatibility with RHEL and CentOS.